# How to create a view which has consolidated information from multiple tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've made up this example as a similar situation to the one I'm working on.

Input tables:

*Team table*

```
TeamID | TeamName
=================
     1 | Alpha
     2 | Beta
     3 | Charlie
     4 | Delta
```

*Member table*

```
TeamID | MemberID | MemberName | Age
====================================
     1 |        1 | Anne       |  10
     1 |        2 | Bob        |  20
     2 |        1 | Carol      |  30
     2 |        2 | David      |  40
     3 |        1 | Elaine     |  30
     3 |        2 | Fred       |  20
     4 |        1 | Geoff      |  50
```

*Job table*

```
TeamID | JobID | Earned | Status
===================================
     1 |     1 |    50  | Complete
     1 |     2 |    75  | InProgress
     2 |     1 |    80  | Complete
     3 |     1 |    50  | InProgress
```

I'm trying to create a view which has consolidated information from those 3 input tables:

```
TeamID | TeamName | IsAbove35 | HasBeenPaid | AllJobsComplete
===============================================================
     1 | Alpha    |         0 |           1 |                0
     2 | Beta     |         1 |           1 |                1
     3 | Charlie  |         0 |           1 |                0
     4 | Delta    |         1 |           0 |                0
```

*IsAbove35* should contain 1 if any of the team members are above 35 years in age (otherwise 0)

*HasBeenPaid* should contain 1 if the earnings for a team are more than 0

*AllJobsComplete* should contain 1 if the team has any job entries and they are all complete

I can work out how to do some of the parts individually, e.g.

*IsAbove35*

```
select t.TeamID,
case when m.Age is null then 0 else 1 end as IsAbove35
from Team t left outer join Member m
on t.TeamID = m.TeamID
and Age > 35
```

*HasBeenPaid*

```
select t.TeamID, case when SUM(Earned) > 0 then 1 else 0 end as HasBeenPaid
from Team t left outer join Job j
on t.TeamID = j.TeamID
group by t.teamid
```

But I'm not sure how to calculate the field 'AllJobsComplete' and also how to put all those columns together into 1 view.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: + for nicely formatted question with example, clear explanation and expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it is using correlated sub-queries in CASE statements:

```
SELECT 
* 
, CASE WHEN EXISTS 
    (SELECT * FROM dbo.Member m WHERE m.TeamID = t.TeamID AND m.Age > 35) 
   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsAbove35 
, CASE WHEN (SELECT SUM(Earned) FROM Job j WHERE j.TeamID = t.TeamID) > 0
   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS HasEarnings
, CASE WHEN EXISTS
    (SELECT * FROM Job j WHERE j.TeamID = t.TeamID AND Status = 'Complete')
    AND NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT * FROM Job j WHERE j.TeamID = t.TeamID AND Status <> 'Complete')
   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS AllJobsComplete
FROM dbo.Team t
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e2fbe/1)**

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer.  SQLFiddle looks very interesting too, I hadn't heard of it before.